# PQsendQueryPrepared - send values and memory management

Tags: c, libpq

I want to send binary data in an asynchronous way to PostgreSQL via libpg's method

```
int PQsendQueryPrepared(PGconn *conn,
                        const char *stmtName,
                        int nParams,
                        const char * const *paramValues,
                        const int *paramLengths,
                        const int *paramFormats,
                        int resultFormat);
```

However, I was not able to find any information about the memory management of passed parameters.

I run this command, and the code continues in a non-blocking manner. When can I free (or rewrite) `paramValues` data? Do I need to wait until `PQgetResult` returns `NULL` or is data internally copied by libpg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PQsendQueryPrepared()` calls `PQsendQueryGuts()` which in turn serializes `paramValues` with `pqPutnchar()` to `pqPutMsgBytes()` to `memcpy()`.  To me it looks like you are free to do what you want with arguments once the function returns.

While `PQsendQueryPrepared()` *starts* the transfer it may not be *done* till you call `PQgetResult()` which does an implicit flush.

Comment: To be honest, I dont quite understand the second part... `Your data may not serialized over the wire till you call PQgetResult() which does an implicit flush`.  So the serialization occurs in `PQsendQueryPrepared()` or in `PQgetResult()`?

Comment: `PQsendQueryPrepared()` (indirectly) serializes the data.  As far as caller is concerned the arguments can then be reused when the function returns. It then starts sending the data to the server. It is not guaranteed to be done till you call PQgetResult().